# Unity: get object state on collision

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

using Unity3d 4.1.2 and C# Mono.

I have an object (player) that contains this script:

```
string[] colors = new string[] {"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Black", "Purple", "Pink", "Orange"};
public string joeColor;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    SetColorState();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

}

public void SetColorState()
{
    joeColor = colors[Random.Range(0, 7)];
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj)
{
    PlatformMove platform = new PlatformMove();
    platform = obj;
    if(platform.platformColor.ToString() == joeColor.ToString())
    {
        Debug.Log("COLOR MATchED!!!  Joe = " + joeColor.ToString() + " Platform COlor = " + platform.platformColor.ToString());
    }
}
```

What I want to do is detect a collision on a platform object.  Then get a method from that object (platform color)  and if it same as my player object then = true.

As you can see the script above wont work, just been messing around seeing what would happen.

The platform object is randomly instantiated in the game, random color as well.  So I need to detect that specific platform and then get its color state.  What do I need to do?

Comment: What is PlatformMove? A MonoBehaviour?

Comment: yeh its a script ive attached to the "platform" prefab that gets randomly instantiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to extract a component:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj)
{
    PlatformMove platform = obj.gameObject.GetComponent<PlatformMove>();
    if(platform != null){
        if(platform.platformColor.ToString() == joeColor.ToString()) {
            //... do stuff
        }
    } else {
        //... collision object did not have a PlatformMove component.
    }
}
```

It appears you know how you want to handle the color comparison but if you anticipate a lot of collisions I would recommend switching from storing `platformColor` as a `string` to using an `enum` instead.

Comment: Weh ni debug its saying platform is always null?

Comment: @StevenSmith Does the colliding object actually have a `PlatformMove` component attached to it?

Comment: nvm it works! i forgot to attacth the script *facepalm* cheers for that!